# Ng-click is not working with dropdown with search-box?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to place a input box for search in custom dropdown for filtering the countries, but for the searching first time it is working fine (i.e; if I type 'ind', I have two countries with ind and I am able to click on that countries and select, but when I again edit the search box for another list of countries, the ng-click is not working and I am unable to select the item from list).

Html:

```
<div  class="predtoptn" id="dvCountryLstdopn">
    <input type="text" class="form-control frmsrch" ng-model="somvar.countryName"  placeholder="Search Items"/>
        <ul class="predtsct">
          <li class="prfdwn" ng-repeat="countriesLst in ctrylst| filter:somvar:strict" ng-click="countryIdFunc(countriesLst.countryId,countriesLst.countryName)">{{countriesLst.countryName}}</li>
         </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
vm.countryIdFunc = function (Id, txt) { vm.cntryId = Id; vm.cntryIdTxt = txt; }
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors in your developer console?

Comment: give us a plunker with this behavior

Comment: @David R no errors,but ng-click is not working fot the second time.

Comment: Can you right click on your `<li>` text and select `Inspect Element` and confirm whether you have the `onclick....` attribute set to `countryIdFunc(...)` function in the generated html?

Comment: @David R yes on-click is there,but first search it is working but when I edit the same search text it is not working,but Iam able to see the click function when i inspect.

Comment: please make sure countryIdFunc is added to scope element.

Comment: Yup, You should be adding your `countryIdFunc` to your scope.

Comment: Can you please post your controller code?

Comment: @David R I updated the code,in the function Iam passing id and name

Comment: I guess, you are using viewmodel as `vm` (pointing to `this`) in your controller. You should be using `$scope` in place of `vm`. It should be,  `$scope.countryIdFunc = function (Id, txt) { $scope.cntryId = Id; $scope.cntryIdTxt = txt; }`

Comment: @David R  I tried with $scope also but it is not working

Comment: Can you please put your code (working) in a plunkr (or) fiddle and share us the link to troubleshoot?

Comment: vm.countryIdFunc try change to $scope.countryIdFunc and check. Also make sure don't forgot to add controller controllerAs: 'vm' in route.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like the below in your template,

```
<li class="prfdwn" ng-repeat="countriesLst in ctrylst| filter:somvar:strict">
    <span ng-click="countryIdFunc(countriesLst.countryId,countriesLst.countryName)">
        {{countriesLst.countryName}}
    </span>
</li>
```